# How to join two tables (two models) using django ORM

Tags: sqlite, django-models, join, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I am new in programming& django. I have some models with a Foreing Key and I have to join two tables: ComponentInstance & ComponentShipment.  My new table should have table ComponentInstance with fields ('component', 'serial_number', 'condition_received', 'date_received', 'received_from', 'quantity') and information with new fields ('date_shipped', 'shipped_to', 'shipped_condition', 'invoice') from table ComponentShipment. My table ComponentShipment is connected to table ComponentInstance by field'component', however not all 'componnets' are shipped. So in my new table if component was not shipped new fields ('date_shipped', 'shipped_to', 'shipped_condition', 'invoice') from table ComponentShipment will be be Null.

```
class ComponentInstance(models.Model):
    component = models.ForeignKey('Component', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    serial_number = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    customer = models.ForeignKey('Customer', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    condition_received = models.ForeignKey("Condition", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_received = models.DateField(default=django.utils.timezone.now)
    time_create = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    time_update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='updated_by_user', null=True, blank=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='created_by_user', null=True, blank=True)
    received_from = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    staff_received = models.ForeignKey("StoreStaff", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=1)
    unit = models.ForeignKey('QuantityType', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    location = models.ForeignKey('Location', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    notes = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.component} {'S/N  '} {self.serial_number}"

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Component"
        verbose_name_plural = "Components"
        ordering = ('component',)


class ComponentShipment(models.Model):
    component = models.ForeignKey('ComponentInstance', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_shipped = models.DateField(default=django.utils.timezone.now)
    shipped_to = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    shipped_condition = models.ForeignKey("Condition", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    invoice = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    staff_shipped = models.ForeignKey("StoreStaff", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    scrapped_company = models.ForeignKey('RepairCompany', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.component} {self.date_shipped} {self.shipped_to}'
```

I was trying to join this two tables in different ways but nothing works;( How is it possible to accomplish this? Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to join,
Just take a single object from ComponentShipment & then you can access data from your same object.
Like,

```
componentShipment = ComponentShipment.objects.get(component = 'Id value of component')
```

Now you can access the values from your ComponentInstance model,

```
print(componentShipment.serial_number)
print(componentShipment.customer)
```

Hope this will helpful.